# perform_segue_with_identifier not working (gathers data but does not display next view)

Tags: ios, objective-c, segue

I'm writing an application and I would like to make it so that after the first time a user logs, subsequent app launches do not direct them to the login screen but instead they are taken to the main app screen.  I store their information in a p-list, retrieve it and then pass it our web service.  If the web service returns a status of success the following code is executed.  For some strange reason though the target of the segue is never displayed.  I put breakpoints in the target of the segue's controller and the program DOES get there but the login screen is still displayed.

```
if (success) {
    loginUID = jsonData[@"user_details"][@"id"];
    loginEmail = jsonData[@"user_details"][@"email"];
    loginUsername = jsonData[@"user_details"][@"username"];
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"login_success" sender:self];
}
```

Is there something that I am doing wrong??  This makes no sense to me! Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you in advance for your time and energy,
Yuchen

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
UIStoryboard *storyboard = self.storyboard;
        DestinationViewController *dc = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"DestController"];
        [dc setModalTransitionStyle:UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve];
        [dc setYouVar:toYourValue];
        [self presentViewController:dc animated:YES completion:NULL];
```

Don't forget to setup Identifier to your view controller in your storyboard

Comment: Thanks! I am trying this now!

Comment: I tried this but it causes my application to crash :(.  I commented out the [dc setYouVar:toYourValue]; and replaced it with [dc setValue: loginUID forKey:@"idFromOtherView"]; (and other variables i'm passing.)  However it crashes before I even get to the [dc setValue: ...] on the [dc setModalTransitionStyle:] line...   Any ideas??

Comment: Thank you for your time and energy Anton.  I seemed to have solved my issue by moving my code to the viewDidAppear as opposed to calling it from viewDidLoad.  I do appreciate the suggestion tho!

Comment: Value it's example of getter, on there receiving controller create own getter.